# Javascript regEx email limited to 3 domains

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I need to validate certain email addresses on the client side before the server side, they are limited to 3 domains, so for example

```
email@me.com
email@you.com
email@us.com
```

It can contain the standard combo of letters, numbers, underscore, hyphen, period etc before the @ but the key requirement being "me.com", "you.com" or "us.com".

I'm shocking at regexes and have been at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for about 30mins but cant get anywhere close...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just find any email regex, take the part before the `@`, and replace the part after it with
`(me|you|us)\.com$`

Comment: ok so why doesn't /^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@(me|you|us)\.com$/ work?

Comment: It should. How are you using the regex?

Comment: for email validation... http://regexr.com?35bdd test here doesnt work... sorry I'm terrible with regEx

Comment: @Oli_M for your test there, as you're using `^` and `$`, you need to enable the "multiline" flag

Comment: sorry they work, just not on that regex builder... wont be using that again!!